# How to create a protocol hyperlink in Google Docs

Tags: hyperlink, google-docs

I want to add a link to open the Windows Update screen of Settings on my PC. Link to open Windows settings (ms-settings:windowsupdate)

However, it appears Google has strict requirements on what a URL should consist of.

[image: Google disallowing my URL]

Is there anyway around these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Thereis a similar question in Web Applications -> [Google Sheets: insert a non http protocol link?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/137352/88163). The only answer at this time suggested to use a link shortener but the OP commented that it doesn't work.

The answers to another similar question from SO, [Add link to open a local file in Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25565613/1595451) are focused on uploading files to server, so doesn't help in this case, unless you are willing to set a web application to listen for a HTTP GET request triggers a client-server communication on your PC working as server, so it opens the Windows Update screen for Settings. Not recommended.